# Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. In React I am gettinf this error

Tags: html, css, node.js, reactjs, web-deployment

Here I am trying to put that screening function at the radius of the TagCloud Object. The screening function returns different number according to the screen width.
But I am getting that error. Any Solution is most welcome. :)

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "../Skills/Skills.css";
import useWindowSize from "./Screen";

const Skills = () => {
  const shoudLog = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shoudLog.current) {
      shoudLog.current = false;
      const myTags = [
        "JavaScript",
        "CSS",
      
      ];

      const TagCloud = require("TagCloud");
      const container = ".content";

      TagCloud(container, myTags, {
        radius: Screening(),
        maxSpeed: "normal",
        
      });

    }
  }, []);

  const Screening = () => {
    const windowSize = useWindowSize();
    if (windowSize.width > 1240) {
      return 250;
    } else if (windowSize.width < 1240 && windowSize.width > 1000) {
      return 200;
    } else if (windowSize.width < 1000 && windowSize.width > 900) {
      return 180;
    } else if (windowSize.width < 900 && windowSize.width > 750) {
      return 150;
    } else if (windowSize.width < 750 && windowSize.width > 600) {
      return 130;
    } else if (windowSize.width < 600) {
      return 200;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="skillsset" id="skills">
      <h1 className="skills-title">Skills</h1>
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default Skills;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

With [the rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), you can't use hooks outside the render method, or use them conditionally.

In this part:

```
const Screening = () => {
  const windowSize = useWindowSize();
  // ...
}
```

You are using a hook inside a nested function, which is a no-no. You might want to do something like this:

```
// put the hook *directly* in the render method
const windowSize = useWindowSize();

const Screening = () => {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Could you please write the complete code? I will be grateful. I am unable to get this.